# cinema4D - Use Boole Object with Extruded Spline

Tags: 3d, boolean, spline, nurbs, cinema-4d

### **Background**

I drew a letter (that's about as far as my drawing skills go) by hand using the `Freehand` Spline tool and extruded it using the `Extrude Nurbs`.

[image: letter P]

Now as you can see the letter is a `P` and so I need to subtract the center of it. Therefore I want to use the `Boole` tool subtracting a little spline (extruded as well) from the large `P`. Here are my splines:

[image: splines]

I added `P` and `pSub` to the `Bool` and set it to **A subtract B** (which works when using a normal cube and a sphere for example). Now the result is not any different from the top picture, A does **not** subtract B.

### **Note**

The center little spline is longer than the outer one (the objects are laying –> ”longer“ as in the y-value being higher).

### **Question**

Is there a way to fix this and to cut out `pSub` from `P` so that it is an actual *P*?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The bool-object only works with polygonal geometry. Simply select both splines in the object-manager and do a right-click. In the context-menu there is an option like 'combine and delete' or 'merge and delete' (i am using a german version) that combines the selected objects into a single one and deletes the base-objects. 
Depending on the complexity of the resulting spline you may have to deactivate the automatic creation of top-surfaces in the extrude-object
and fill the holes manually using the 'fill-polygon-hole'-tool.

Second approach: extrude both splines individually first (creating polygonal geometry) and use a bool on the extruded objects.

IMHO the first approach is a more 'clean'-way to solve your problem.